# Creating Stub for C# Generic Type Method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method: (simplified)

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public List<T> GetEntity<T>()
    {
       return GetFromDatabase<T>(); //Retrieve from database base on Type parameter
    }
}
```

For testing purpose, I want to create a stub from which I want 'Foo' should be returned with some data:

```
public class DataAccessStub : IDataAccess
{
    public List<T> GetEntity<T>()
    {
       List<Foo> listFoo = new List<Foo>();
       Foo foo = new Foo();
       foo.Name = "Some Name";
       listFoo.Add(foo);

       return listFoo; // I want Foo to be returned
    }
}
```

Since `T` has not identified what type it is yet, I can't return `List<Foo>`. Compiler error will occur. So How can I write a stub for this kind of generic method?

**Edit: Changed the code a little bit. The first method will retrieve from the database base on Type Parameter. The second is a stub for testing.
Sorry that I am not sure if this explain what I want to mention.**

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with the first stub you have? The caller will need to pass (or have in context) the value of T.

Comment: I don't understand the question, isn't the first example what you want?

Comment: Why do you have `List<T>` as the return type if you already know it's a `List<Foo>`?

Comment: What are you really trying to do ?  It doesn't make sense to have a generic method that only returns a concrete type..

Comment: I have added some more to explain more about what I'd like to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    interface IA
{
    List<T> Get<T>();
}

class StubA : IA
{
    public List<T> Get<T>()
    {
        var item = new Foo();
        var data = new List<Foo> {item};
        return new List<T>(data.Cast<T>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me the answer. :)